# How can I update a configuration file on zookeeper?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I uploaded a configuration folder for Solr core to Apache zookeeper using zkClient. 
When I delete a file in my local configuration and update it to Zookeeper again, I can't see the change reflected in Solr admin page.
Could somebody please explain how to update/delete files from zookeeper?
Also where to find the physical files in zookeeper folder?

Answer (score 5):

In order to upload a modified file in zookeeper client, you need to:

- remove the old file from Zookeeper and
- upload the new one and
- restart the Solr nodes (depending on the change, you could reload the collection instead).

For instance if you need to update solrconfig.xml, you can:
a) clear old file on zookeeper (otherwise depending from the client version you'll get an error):

```
zkcli.sh --zkhost <ZK_HOST>:<ZK_PORT> -cmd clear /configs/<MY_COLLECTION>/solrconfig.xml
```

b) upload the updated file:

```
zkcli.sh --zkhost <ZK_HOST>:<ZK_PORT> -cmd putfile /configs/<MY_COLLECTION>/solrconfig.xml  /<MY_UPDATED_FILE_LOCAL_FOLDER>/solrconfig.xml
```

c) Restart the Solr nodes.

I believe your Solr files should be in `/configs/<MY_COLLECTION>`.

Comment: In addition this is the endpoint to operate a collection reload :
.../solr/admin/collections?action=RELOAD&name=<name>